# Incorrect Date Format and date generates

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, datetime

I have variable of a type `DateTime objApplicationSummaryInfo.AdmissionDate`. I am trying to assign a value, such as

```
objApplicationSummaryInfo.AdmissionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
       TextBox3.Text.ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy", null);
```

But when i am assigning a value like `27/09/2012`to a `textbox3`, the variable `objApplicationSummaryInfo.AdmissionDate` takes a value `1/27/2012 12:00:09`.  The format as well as the date comes back incorrect.

What possible code am I missing and what can be an alternate solution. Thanks for assistance.

Comment: `01/27/2012` or `09/27/2012` look at the question again !

Comment: You should use MM for months (mm is for minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mm` is minutes.

`MM` is months

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Your code should be:

```
objApplicationSummaryInfo.AdmissionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
   TextBox3.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

You will also need to set the culture:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

objApplicationSummaryInfo.AdmissionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
   TextBox3.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", culture);
```

Otherwise it will use the culture of the machine running the code.

Comment: thanks sir but the format still not coming correct. i want dd/MM/yyyy. it is coming as MM/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

`"dd/mm/yyyy"` should probably be `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

- `mm` - is for minutes
- `MM` - is for months

---

```
objApplicationSummaryInfo.AdmissionDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
       TextBox3.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: Thanks sir but the format still not coming correct. i want dd/MM/yyyy. it is coming as MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @Abhishekgupta - **Where** does it come out like that? `AdmissionDate ` is a `DateTime`, it doesn't have associated formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with - dd/MM/yyyy

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

hey are you Testing on localHost try it on Server i will work on server but not on localhots